# When importing from Googlesheets, returns a list I can't convert to date in R

Tags: r, google-sheets

when I import from GoogleSheets one of the variables comes as a list. This is a sample:

```
> dataset$my_date[1:4]
[[1]]
[1] "2019-06-25 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2019-06-25 UTC"

[[3]]
[1] "2019-06-25 UTC"

[[4]]
[1] "2019-06-25 UTC"
```

But when I try to convert this list to date, it returns me:

```
> as.Date(dataset$my_date[1:4])
Error in as.Date.default(dataset$my_date[1:4]) : 
  do not know how to convert 'dataset$my_date[1:4]' to class “Date”
```

Is there a way to set this variable as vector when reading with `read_sheet()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `list` and according to `?as.Date`

> x - The as.Date methods accept character strings, factors, logical NA and objects of classes "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct"

```
methods(as.Date)
#[1] as.Date.character   as.Date.default     as.Date.factor      as.Date.IDate       as.Date.numeric     as.Date.POSIXct    
#[7] as.Date.POSIXlt     as.Date.vctrs_sclr* as.Date.vctrs_vctr*
```

As there is no `list` method for `as.Date`, we need to concatenate them with `c` to convert to a `vector` (invoked with `do.call` )

```
as.Date(do.call(c, dataset$my_date))
```

If there are `NULL` elements, convert it to `NA`

```
dataset$my_data[sapply(dataset$my_data, is.null)] <- NA
as.Date(do.call(c, dataset$my_date))
```

Or using `unlist` (if it is not a `Datetime` class i.e. a `character` vector)

```
as.Date(unlist(dataset$my_date))
```

---

It can be reproduced with

```
lst1 <- list(Sys.time(), Sys.time())
as.Date(lst1)
```

> Error in as.Date.default(lst1) :
> do not know how to convert 'lst1' to class “Date”

By converting to `vector`

```
as.Date(do.call(c, lst1))
#[1] "2020-09-13" "2020-09-13"
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, just a question, this list has null values and when I apply `unlist` or `do.call` it drops those values and the vector is shorter than the original list. Please, do you know how to preserve the original length?

Comment: @Manu Are you sure it is `NA` and not `NULL`?  `lst1 <- list(Sys.time(), Sys.time(), NA)#
 as.Date(do.call(c, lst1))#
[1] "2020-09-13" "2020-09-13" NA` because this is working for me

Comment: @Manu try `dataset$my_data[sapply(dataset$my_data, is.null)] <- NA;
    as.Date(do.call(c, dataset$my_date))`

Comment: @Manu The update should work `lst1 <- list(Sys.time(), Sys.time(), NULL); lst1[sapply(lst1, is.null)] <- NA; as.Date(do.call(c, lst1))#[1] "2020-09-13" "2020-09-13" NA`

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun, you know the function `read_sheet` from googlesheets imports a sheet as a tibble but when there are null values it converts to a list. Have a great day!